# Catch circular dependency between observables

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I have a user-programming scenario where user can end up creating two observables that depend on each other. RxJS does not allow circular dependencies, as far as I can see, the memory or stack reaches its limits and the `onError` callback is triggered with the value `true`.

How to detect the circular dependency explicitly and throw a more descriptive error message?

This codes illustrates how to create a circular dependency in RxJS:

```js
var obsA,
    obsB;

obsA = Rx.Observable
    .returnValue(42)
    .combineLatest(obsB, function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

obsB = Rx.Observable
    .returnValue(42)
    .combineLatest(obsA, function (b, a) {
        return b + a;
    });


obsA
    .subscribe(function (val) {
        console.log('onNext:' + val);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.error('onError: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('onCompleted');
    });
```

The error message is simply `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the original question does not create a circular dependency.  At the time you define `ObsA`, `ObsB` is `undefined` and so what you've really done is call `combineLatest(undefined, function ...)`.  So the error you are seeing is because you are passing `undefined` to  `combinedLatest()`.

It actually takes some effort to create a real circular dependency. If you use `defer`, then you would have a true circular dependency:

```js
var obsA,
    obsB,
    aRef,
    bRef;

aRef = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
    return obsA;
});

bRef = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
    return obsB;
});

obsA = Rx.Observable
    .returnValue(42)
    .combineLatest(bRef, function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
    });

obsB = Rx.Observable
    .returnValue(42)
    .combineLatest(aRef, function (b, a) {
        return b + a;
    });

obsA.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>
```

**Now** that is a real circular dependency.  Unfortunately you still get the same error, though with a much deeper stack trace:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
/* ... stack ... */
```

There is no fool-proof way to detect cycles.  You could wrap the observables in a new observable and detect recursive calls to your subscribe method.  But such an algorithm would be defeated if the underlying observables are using `subscribeOn` or `publish` or `concat` anything else that delays the actual circular subscriptions.

The best suggestion I have is to append a `catch` clause that checks for a range error and replaces it with a better error:

```js
var obsA,
    obsB,
    aRef,
    bRef;

aRef = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
    return obsA;
});

bRef = Rx.Observable.defer(function () {
    return obsB;
});

obsA = Rx.Observable
    .returnValue(42)
    .combineLatest(bRef, function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        var isStackError = e instanceof RangeError && e.message === 'Maximum call stack size exceeded';
    
        return Rx.Observable.throw(isStackError ? new Error('Invalid, possibly circular observables.') : e);
    });

obsB = Rx.Observable
    .returnValue(42)
    .combineLatest(aRef, function (b, a) {
        return b + a;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        var isStackError = e instanceof RangeError && e.message === 'Maximum call stack size exceeded';
    
        return Rx.Observable.throw(isStackError ? new Error('Invalid, possibly circular observables.') : e);
    });

obsA.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>
```

Comment: You are of course right, there was no cyclic dependency. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Here is a outline of a solution I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/xGhnC/ ... it uses the classic spreadsheet algorithm for detecting cyclic dependencies. As far as I can see, it should not cause problems with subscribeOn, publish, or concat. Am I right?

Comment: Oh yeah if you can wrap the actual create methods of the observables, then your method will work because you are detecting cyclic dependencies in the "build" step.  Here is a minor tweak to ensure your state variables get reset if an error occurs: http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/xGhnC/2/  However, I can still defeat your check by using `defer`: http://jsfiddle.net/bman654/xGhnC/3/ (notice no error when I call `a()` to create my observable and then if I subscribe, we get your original problem.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Wondering why you add try/finally. If there is a cyclic dependency, I dont need to recover. I am converting from a DSL, so I can prevent stuff like defer.

Comment: ah if you do not need to recover then yes you probably do not need the try/finally.